# GWT Resolver attribute of relationship can not be resolved

Tags: gwt, jpa-2.0, requestfactory, resolver

I'm working on a GXT project using JPA for persistence, but I'm facing an issue with bidirectionnal relationship persistence.

I have those two Entities :

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ACTV_REQ", catalog = "erpdb")
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED"))
    @NamedQueries(value = { 
            @NamedQuery(name = "findByPerson", query="select object(m) from ActvReq m where m.people= :people")
    })
    public class ActvReq extends BaseEntity {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PPL_ID")
        @NotNull
        private People people;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ACTV_TYP_ID")
        private ActivityTyp actvTyp;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name= "PPL_ACTV_RIGHT_ID")
        private PeopleActvRight pplActvRight;

        @Column(name = "DESCR")
        private String desc;
    }
```

And :

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PPL_ACTV_RIGHT", catalog = "erpdb")
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED"))
    @PeopleActvRightBeanConstraint
    @NamedQueries(value = { 
            @NamedQuery(name = "findByPeople", query="select object(m) from PeopleActvRight m where m.people= :people")
    })
    public class PeopleActvRight extends BaseEntity {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ACTV_TYP_ID")
        @NotNull    
        ActivityTyp type;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="PPL_ID")
        @NotNull    
        People people;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ACTV_RIGHT_ID")
        ActvRight actvRight;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="pplActvRight",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<ActvReq> actvRequests = new ArrayList<ActvReq>();
    }
```

(I did not copy getters and setters but thoses methods exists.)

For the persistence of ActvReqProxy, it's basically done that way in my EditorPresenter :

```java
    getRequestContext().persistAndReturn(getModel()).with("actvTyp","people","pplActvRight").fire(new Receiver<M>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(M response) {
        unsetContext();
        onSaveSuccess( response );
        }       
    });
```

And the response pplActvRight is already null in the response I get, but in getModel() pplActvReqProxy is set.

On server side I've a service which calls the following method of my DAO :

```java
    public ActvReq persistAndReturn(ActvReq entity){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(entity);
        em.close;
        return entity;
    }
```

And when I'm trying to persist a ActvReqProxy from my editor, using method with("pplActvRight","people",actvType"), I don't get any errors, but in my DB the entity is not entirely persisted. I mean a new ActvReq is created in the DB but field PPL_ACTV_RIGHT_ID remains null. (It works fine for people and actvTyp)

EDIT : In fact I assume the problem is located on GWT Resolver in resolveDomainValue, it can not resolve the attribute pplActvRight. It's as if my EntityProxy object doesn't exists on server-side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure pplActvRight property is set on `ActvReqProxy` at the moment that you persist `ActvReqProxy`? Also can you show the code that persists `ActvReqProxy`?

Comment: Well it seems that everything is right as long as we are in the client side. But once in server side pplActvRight is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the beginning of `persistAndReturn` on server side it is already `null`? If so, then at least we know that it has nothing to do with JPA.

And you're sure that on client side it is set to something other than `null` on proxy before calling `persistAndReturn`? You can easily verify it: using Eclipse debugger it is possible to see JSON code to which proxy will be serialized (one of fields of proxy that you can see when you select proxy object in debugger). Please make sure that `pplActvRight` key is there with not-null value.

If so, maybe you should debug GWT source code that translates proxies to server-side entities to check what is being done with that `pplActvRight` property (why isn't it assigned to corresponding `ActvReq` server side instance). I can't remember what the class name doing this stuff was but if you won't be able to find it I can search it for you.

Comment: First of all, I'm sure that right before calling my service on the server pplActvRightProxy is not null, and is filled with the right values. However, about the binding between a client-side EntityProxy and a server-side Entity, if it's done, as I think, by class "package com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.Resolver" in the method  resolveDomainValue I notice that it can cannot resolve pplActvRight 'cause the object domain is null for pplActvRight (however it works for people and actvTyp).

Comment: Do you think it's possible that my problem has nothing to do with ActvReq but only with PplActvReq, as it's the only attribute it can't resolve? 'cause I've made exactly the same thing for the relationship with pplActvReq and ActvTyp and People. Maybe I've made a mistake when I persist it since I've got another problem with pplActvRight. I can delete a pplActvRight or create one but when I'm trying to edit it I get the same error it can not resolve it and I get the error : The requested entity is not available on the server. Do you think it's linked?

Comment: The error: "The requested entity is not available on the server" seemts to suggest that it has something to do with id/stableId of proxy. RF tries to locate on entities server side by finding them using id. Could you show the code of your [Locator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html) object for PplActvReq? Or findPplActvReq method (I don't know wchich mechanism do you use). It may be really important.

Comment: Well about the locator for ActvReq or PeopleActvRight it is quite hard to give you a sample code 'cause it's generic but it's seems to work fine everywhere else. Then I don't think it's what raise the problem. About the method find. I've got in my DAO a method findById(Long id){return em().find(persistentClass, id);}

Comment: Please, start removing properties of PeopleActvRight one after another to the point when it start persist/update correctly. I think there is a chance that one of PeopleActvRight properties may be reponsible for problem.

Comment: Just before answering your question I'd like to add that in my locator when I call the method findById on my dao, it's called with the right ID I mean the ID exists in DB, but "return dao.findbyId(id)" returns null. If it helps...

Comment: So in other words, even though entity with given ID exists, code: `em().find(persistentClass, id);` returns `null`?

Comment: No this time I got something not null but quite strange. I've found something in debug view in eclipse. It appears that my locator is using the wrong DAO... I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was finally a really dumb mistake. I set the wrong locator in my EntityProxy.

Comment: I'm glad you solved this one. It was tough one. But you learned a lot about inner working of RF by the way :-).